# Animated navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, navbar

I'm wonder how to make a navigation bar animate when you scroll down some. One example I know is [FlatIcon](http://www.flaticon.com/). I just need to know how to get the website to recognize when the person scrolls down. I can do the animating myself

Comment: use javascript  like this **var mouseX = window.scrollY;** in mouseX when you scroll down this will increases in pixels

Comment: Could you by chance go into more details about this? I'm a little confused

Comment: Ok I'll Explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to change your Menu height after user scroll more than 90 pixel

JAVA SCRIPT CODE

```
//ONSCROLL FUNCTION TO HIDE MENU
function hideMenu(){
    var mouseX = window.scrollY;
    var menu = document.getElementById("pageHeader");
    if(mouseX > 90){
        menu.style.height = "50px";
        menu.style.transition = "height 1s"; /*This is Optional */
    }else {
        menu.style.height = "100PX";
        menu.style.transition = "height 1s";
    }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll",hideMenu);
```

CSS CODE. IT IS SIMPLE JUST FOR UNDERSTAND

```
<style>
#pageHeader {
height: 100px;
}
</style>
```

HTML CODE

```
<div id="pageHeader">
<!-- HERE IS YOUR MENU ITEMS OR THEIR CONTAINER... -->
</div>
```

In this code this function hideMenu() always starts when user scroll down your page. When they scroll down more than 90px the height of your menu is 50px. You can add more Effects by using if else condition...
Hope this will help you. If you have further question comment them..

Comment: Got it, explained very well. Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

You can fire a jquery function and enable a class that places a `position:fixed` via CSS. [Live Example](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/ORRNBK)

HTML

```
<div id="nav-bar"></div>
<div id="some-content"></div>
<div id="anchor-point"></div>
<div id="sticky"></div>
<div id="some-content2"></div>
```

CSS

```
#nav-bar{
   margin-top: 0;
   background-color: #000;
   height:60px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 1;
   width:100%
}
#some-content{
   height: 500px;
}
#sticky{
   width:100%;
   height:50px;
   background-color:#ccc;
}

#sticky.stick {
    margin-top: 60px !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}
#some-content2{
   height: 500px;
}
```

JQuery/JS

```
function stick_sticky() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#anchor-point').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
        $('#anchor-point').height($('#sticky').outerHeight());
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height(0);
    }
 }

 $(function() {
     $(window).scroll(stick_sticky);
     stick_sticky();
 });
```